# Redux mapStateToProps not workking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to connect a Redux container to a component. I'm just starting out with redux and I feel like I might be missing something conceptual but I can't figure out what.

The problem is that mapStateToProps doesn't even run when it is in a different file than the component.

My code:
index.js :

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"
import App from "./components/App"
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import { combinedReducers} from "./reducers/changePageReducer"
import { createStore } from "redux"


ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store = {createStore(combinedReducers)}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>, 
    document.querySelector("#root"))
```

App.js component

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
    logger = () => {
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick = {this.logger}>Click me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

container

```
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import App from "../components/App"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return {buttonText : state.page}
} 

const changePageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(App)

export default changePageContainer
```

I also have one simple reducer and action defined. The interesting thing for me is that if I run the code in one file (the container and the components) I can log out the state in props just fine but if I separate them this way I only log an empty object for props.
I beleive I should somehow connect the component to the container but I didn't find anywhere how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From examples you have provided, it looks like you haven't imported your container at all.

Please, try to import `ChangePageContainer` in `index.js` and use it instead of `App`.

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"
// import App from "./components/App"
import ChangePageContainer from './containers/changePageContainer';
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import { combinedReducers} from "./reducers/changePageReducer"
import { createStore } from "redux"

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store = {createStore(combinedReducers)}>
        // <App/>
        <ChangePageContainer />
    </Provider>, 
    document.querySelector("#root"))
```